# Cleaning quotes in a string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a string:

```
"Very ""Good"" title"
```

and I need to make it look like this:

```
Very "Good" title
```

how can I do this?

Sorry for the lack of description. Here is what is going on:
I have a file, where line like:

```
"Very ""Good"" title" 21 1231 1111 [zcz]
```

and i need to split in to

```
"Very ""Good"" title"
21
1231
1111 
[zcz]
```

and then, `"Very ""Good"" title"` replace with `Very "Good"" title`

Comment: did you mean remove first 2 and last 2 `"` ?

Comment: Please describe your need more precise.  Do you want to remove single `"` characters and replace double `"` characters with a single character?

Comment: show us your current code where you're trying to do this, other way it is off topic

Comment: You're going to have to be more precise about the exact rules in place. How do you determine what quotes have to be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a regex with a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)? Specifically: `"(?!")`.

```
String s = "\"Very \"\"Good\"\" title\"";

System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\"(?!\")", ""));
```

```
Very "Good" title
```

I'm assuming here that you want to replace every run of n quotes with n-1 quotes, which is equivalent to deleting the last quote in such a run. This is exactly what we're doing with this regex; we're matching and removing all quotes that are not followed by another quote:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mnp4fw6SpnppHo28)

Comment: Great method but, seems that if there is a string like `Hello """"World"""" !`, instead of producing `Hello ""World"" !`,  this method is producing `Hello """World""" !` (because only the last `"` in each `"` sequence is replaced.  (Well... I am not sure if it actually is what the OP wants...)

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "Very \"Good\" title";
System.out.println(s);
```

Result = Very "Good" title

Answer (score 0):

Get a good CSV parser that can handle Microsoft Excel sheets. The parser will do the work for you, and you can concentrate on the real task.

Or, if the data comes from another source, get a pre-built parser for that format. Someone else has surely written one. Don't do work that others have already done successfully.

Comment: How is this at all helpful?

Comment: @cYn This looks like a line of a CSV file (with the field seperaqtor=" "). The CSV parser should be able to parse this string  into seperate fields in the one go.

Comment: But you're telling him to use an M2 Machine gun at a paintball range. It's over kill. There are easy ways around it just like the answer from arshajii. He has to first find a CSV parser, integrate it into his environment, and then read the documentation on it on how to replace/ignore characters.

Comment: @cYn I don't find it is a machine gun for this problem: although "quote cleaning" seems a trivial task which arshajii's method mostly work, the initial splitting of string is going to cause a lot of trouble.  OP cannot use space as delimiter to do `String.split()`, because of the spaces in the String.  Using a CVS parser is actually a good idea to proper deal with such file format

Comment: I do see all points mentioned in here. But if a person is asking a simple question to do a simple task, suggesting him to find parsers that requires documentation won't be of much help.

Comment: The original question didn’t provide much context, so I tried to guess that, based on experience. In the end, using a parser (high level) instead of splitting strings (low level) will probably save many hours of debugging. Especially if the data corruption is only noticed some steps later in the processing.